# Get relative URL in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a relative path:

```
~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css"
```

and I have a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="siteUrl" value=""/>
```

In MVC I want to store the fully qualified URL into the hidden field. I have tried:

```
<input type="hidden" id="siteUrl" value="@Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css")"/>
```

and

```
<input type="hidden" id="siteUrl" value="@HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css")"/>
```

But those are both returning a physical path, I need the URL. I have also tried using `UriBuilder` however this doesn't work for me because while it might work on my localhost it doesn't when I publish it to my IIS server.

I have also tried:

```
<input type="hidden" id="siteUrl" value="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css")"/>
```

but it returns `/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css`

and in my MVC controller I tried:

```
Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css");
```

which also doesn't do what I need.

**Background:**

I store that FQ URL into the hidden field and then I access it in JS, in JS when I use a relative url it doesnt know how to use it correctly because with MVC for each link the path changes and it just tacks the relative string on to the end like this:
`http://localhost/~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`

If I just remove the `~/` then it works `http://localhost/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`, but when I click to go to a new link the path is no longer good: `http://localhost/newLink/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`

The Url on my localhost is `http://localhost/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`
and on my server its `http://server/productName/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css` I dont want to code for some static name in case the base server url were to change in the future.

So how do I get the fully qualified URL for a relative path?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `Server.MapPath` just returns the physical path, I need the fully qualified URL i.e. `http://domain.com/productName/Content/...`

Comment: Your application is deployed as "webapplication" in prduction whereas it runs as "website" in development server (these are IIS terms). The difference is the virtual path System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath, in this case "productName". Using @Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css") should be what you need, because it includes the virtual path **only** when you need it. You believe it's wrong because you didn't tried to deploy both in IIS Express and Local IIS. When deployed in Local IIS this will contain the application name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what issues you were having with `UriBuilder`, but that's the best method:

```
@{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
    uriBuilder.Path = Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css");
}
<input type="hidden" id="siteUrl" value="@uriBuilder.ToString()"/>
```

You start with `Request.Url`, so you don't have to hard code the host. That way, it should work everywhere you deploy it. Then you alter the `Path`, but you need to use `Url.Content` to replace the `~` with whatever it should be first.

You might want to actually add your own `UrlHelper` extension as well:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string AbsoluteContent(this UrlHelper helper, string contentPath)
    {
        return new Uri(helper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url, helper.Content(contentPath)).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked, thank you so much, I almost became a bald man.. I think the problem I ran into is because I used `Request.Url.AbsolutePath`